# How to disable checkbox options?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, leaflet

I get an error message when loading a map. But when the map fails, I want the "MAP" option to appear in a canceled state, that is, to be non-clickable. how can I do that

```
$('.leaflet-control-layers').text("MAP").hide();// I tried this way but they all disappeared
```

```
        mywms.on("tileerror", function () {
                map.removeLayer(mywms);
                alert("ERROR)")              
        var mywms2 = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                     maxZoom: 17,                     
                })
                map.addLayer(mywms2);
            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your condition, you can do this, just add disbale attribute and css `text-decoration: line-through;`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#check').attr("disabled", true);
 $('#check + label').css("text-decoration","line-through");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="map">
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">Map</label> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `$('.leaflet-control-layers').text("MAP").hide();` to `$('.leaflet-control-layers').text("MAP").disable();`

Answer (score 0):

I think using ID is easier

`<input type="checkbox" id="map">`

`$('#map').hide()`